# Single Sign On - multiple identity provider, optional SSO pages

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs

We have an asp.net application which allows our internal users to access and do many things based on their role. We also have some parts of the application is accessible for general public. 
We need to implement Single sign on to this project using ADFS 3.0. 
I know I can setup the relaying party and set the application to work in SSO. but:

1. How we can implement it to allow general public to access certain pages without login?
2. How we can implement multiple identity provider using ADFS? For example, to access certain pages, general public has register with our application and their authentication will be done through database. However for internal users, they needs to be logged into application using Active Directory. Any ideas?

Appreciate your help!

thanks,
sri

Answer (score 0):

If you setup the ADFS connection via WIF, you can use the web.config allow / deny [construct](https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config) to filter.

ADFS cannot authenticate against a DB.

Federate ADFS with identityserver and use identityserver to do the DB auth.

Then in the ADFS Home Realm Discovery screen, have two connections, one for general public, one for internal.

Comment: Hello nzpcmad, thanks for the reply. I will check on these instructions.